# Migrate Legacy Shared Project to MAUI Class Library

Tags: maui

I do have a project with legacy code that has a bunch of shared libraries with the following structure:

- Project.iOS (Class Library)
- Project.Android (Class Library)
- Project.Shared (Shared Project)

the class libraries have references to the shared project, and the referenced to another shared project which is referenced to a Main App which we are going to migrate to MAUI as well.

Now I want to migrate this to .NET MAUI Class Library, however I haven't found any "How to" for this specific situation.

Is there a way to make this upgrade possible.

Comment: Did you get any where with this? I'm in the same boat, so far nothing on migrating a Shared project.

Comment: how did you solve this Problem? (@Chucky did you get any clean way to do this? same problem here)

Comment: I believe it's as easy as creating a new project **class library** in .NET-SDK style, i.e. .NET 6, 7 or 8 (or a MAUI class library if you want platform specific code in the internal folders). Then just copy over the folders and code from your **shared project**. You then might need to add nuget dependencies to fix the errors (in a shared project I think these are just compiled from the Android/iOS projects?). Once it builds, you can delete the old shared project. And if you set the same name for this new project, hopefully Git will view it as the same project, keeping your commit history.

Comment: @Chucky, that exactly what I ended up doing, need to pay attention for the nuget packages that are not compatible with .net 6, 7 or 8

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking into the [Upgrade Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/?view=net-maui-7.0) for .Net MAUI?

There are specifcs for a [native xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/native-projects?view=net-maui-7.0) project.

Or from a [Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/upgrade-assistant?view=net-maui-7.0) project.

Comment: Hi @Devencc thanks for your reply. Yes, I have tried however however these Project.iOS and Project.Android are not the native projects, these are class libraries that contains code for android and ios that compose another library that are referenced to the native apps that we are having no problem to migrate.